# How to correctly style borders of a CTabItem

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have written an Eclipse plugin which provides some UI which uses the CTabFolder component.

[image: App screenshot]

The CTabItems provided by Eclipse have a blue border when active and a white border when inactive (grey if the CTabItem is an Eclipse View).

The CTabItems which I have created are always bordered in white and the text on the active tab is underlined.

How can I control the style of my CTabItems to more closely match the Eclipse tabs?

EDIT:

I have come up with the following code which extracts the correct colors from the active Eclipse theme.

```
IWorkbench workBench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
ITheme theme = workBench.getThemeManager().getCurrentTheme();
ColorRegistry colreg = theme.getColorRegistry();

Color c1 = colreg.get(IWorkbenchThemeConstants.ACTIVE_TAB_BG_START);
Color c2 = colreg.get(IWorkbenchThemeConstants.ACTIVE_TAB_BG_END);
```

However, this isn't ideal as IWorkbenchThemeConstants is within an eclipse ui internal package.

Is there an alternative public way to reference the same colors referred to by these internal IWorkbenchThemeConstants?

Answer (score 11):

You can use methods for defining gradient on selected and non-selected CTabFolder items. For example

```
CTabFolder folder = new CTabFolder(shell, SWT.BORDER);
folder.setBackground(new Color[]{display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW), display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED)}, new int[]{100}, true);
folder.setSelectionBackground(new Color[]{display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE), display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE)}, new int[]{100}, true);
```

will produces this (ugly) tabs

[image: colored SWT CTabFolder]

So you just have to hit right colors which eclipse have..

Or you could write your own [CTabFolderRenderer](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/CTabFolderRenderer.html) and set it to your CTabFolder instance.

**EDIT**

For Eclipse colors try

```
folder.setSelectionBackground(new Color[]{new Color(display, new RGB(242, 244, 247)), new Color(display, new RGB(157, 167, 195))}, new int[]{100}, true);
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Found the way how to do it correctly

```
folder.setSelectionBackground(new Color[]{display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_TITLE_INACTIVE_BACKGROUND_GRADIENT), display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_TITLE_BACKGROUND)}, new int[]{100}, true);
```

Comment: Writing a new <a href="http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/CTabFolderRenderer.html">CTabFolderRenderer</a> really is a heavy-weight option ;-) It is a bit like writing a Presentation Factory - something you do as the very, very last resort

Comment: Definitely, but it's one of the options. It's there just for completeness ;].

Comment: Any suggestions how I find out the right colors which Eclipse uses?

Comment: Thanks for the extra info but the constants you provided don't produce the same colors as your example where you manually chose colors. I have edited my original question to show some code which will lookup the correct colors but relies on a class in an internal Eclipse package.