# Java SWT - Set ForeGround/Background Color of CTabItem (of CTabFolder)

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, ctabitem

I'm using a CTabFolder with several CTabItems.  I would like to be able to set the background and foreground color of only a single CTabItem's tab.

There is an option for me to set the Font, but I can't find anything for the color or background of just the TabItem itself.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Similar question was already addressed in [How to correctly style borders of a CTabItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649756/how-to-correctly-style-borders-of-a-ctabitem).

It's possible to set foreground (font) color and background (tabitem itself) color/gradient for selected and not selected (others) tabitems, see [CTabFolder javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/CTabFolder.html).

To do it just for one custom tabitem, you'll have to write your own [CTabFolderRenderer](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/CTabFolderRenderer.html), *but it's really heavyweight solution*.